# Error in psycopg2 install (django)

Tags: django, virtual-environment

**error in psycopg2 install in venv**

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
**kwargs
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
ensure_dir(destdir)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
os.makedirs(path)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
```

OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2'

> Please help me on this . What am i doing wrong?
>   thanks in advance

Comment: i cant see you have activated the virtualenv

Comment: it is not but even after activating it i am getting the same error message

Comment: where is your directory located? make sure to make the directory out of linux internal folders, lik etc var and all , create the virtualenv with sudo for better accessibilty, like sudo virtualenv venv then activate it and then try to install

Comment: try with sudo permission required.

Comment: The stack trace looks like it is trying to install with the system Python, which is normally a bad idea. Are you sure your `venv` is activated?

Comment: @FlipperPA venv was activated. the error was regarding the version of the python. i was using 3.5 and the project was written in 2.7 which led to the error.

Comment: Nice catch! You should answer your own question in case someone runs into a similar problem, and so we can upvote it. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Debian/Ubuntu**

Try this one:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev
```

If above not work try this one.

**Python 2**

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev python-dev
```

**Python 3**

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev python3-dev
```

**Additional**

If none of the above solve your issue, try

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

or

`sudo apt install postgresql-server-dev-all`